# Brown circles in yard

Tags: grass

My grass has started to have these spots.  Anybody know what they are and how to treat it?  There has been plenty of rain.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the problem is fusarium blight and I just need to apply an anti-fungal chemical.

Answer (score 2):

Before we can treat, we need to know the "why it happened"; treating without regard to cause is wasteful of time and resources. We can see the dead on top, now we could add information from below the surface. Preferably with a hard metal tube of some kind see if you can pull a plug of soil from dead and green areas down to a depth of 3-4 inches. You can also do this with a trowel or spade but it tends to break apart the plugs in an uncontrolled manner. We might think of watering the ground before pulling the plugs in order to get the cores to hold together but it sounds like the ground will be moist enough already. Also look for mature specimens of the grass to aid in identifying the mix of grasses present.

There should be a clear difference between the plugs from green and bare patches. You may note differences in soil quality, grass plant types and presence of insects (grubs, larvae, and so on). The "plenty of rain" factor can also indicate drowning of roots (is the grass plot in a low lying area?) or encouragement of fungal infections. Note any sign of fungal growth.

This at least will give you an impressive array of information to take to your local garden centre to support any request for authorized products.